# IE can't place focus and cursor on input text boxes after focusing out of tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce

I've just reproduced the same error in tinyMCE fiddle.

here's the link : http://fiddle.tinymce.com/39daab

There are brief descriptions on the page...

following the steps will show you the error I run into...

I've been trying to solve this problem by my own, but I think I'm not able to.

I looked through tinyMCE documentation and bug report pages like a thousand of times,

but I couldn't get a hint for this.

It's really weird that IE can place focus, but can't cursor on input elements.

You can check the current focused element by selecting $('*:focus')...

focusing does work, but placing cursor doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Posting this in case it helps someone else who runs into this. I had a similar issue. It seems like IE9+ has a bug where if the focus is on a dom element that is removed, the focus event on other elements stops working.

In my case I was able to resolve it by doing an $('input').focus() before destroying the rich text editor (CKEditor).

Bug is outlined here:
[Why can I sometimes not type into my <input> in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978235/why-can-i-sometimes-not-type-into-my-input-in-ie)

and here:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9122

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I used the pseudo-selector `$(':input').focus()` to set focus on any input type (rather than just HTML INPUTs) but other than that worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Another similar issue: on our web page we hide and show divs using a fast animation ( .slideDown(100) / .slideUp(100) ). The divs contain input boxes that randomly will fail to get focus on IE9, 10 and 11.

The input boxes show up, but the cursor doesn't change when you hover over them, nothing happens if you click on the input, it's like the input doesn't exist. Sometimes if you hit the tab key it will fix itself and you can focus and get a cursor in the input.

When we removed the animation, or increased the time (to e.g. .slideDown(500) ) it seemed like it started working - we couldn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same problem with tinyMce 4.4.0 version.
window.focus() resolve the problem in iE11.

```
function closeTinyMce(){
  tinymce.remove();
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.focus();
  },10)
}
```

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DWfaab/1